# String "yyyy-mm" to "mmm" convert to month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, date

Does anyone knows how to convert string 2010-01 to JAN  in mysql ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add "-01" to the end of your date string, then something like this this should work, using `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2010-01-01', '%b');  /* shows 'Jan' */
```

Comment: and use UPPER : `UPPER(DATE_FORMAT('2010-01-01', '%b'));`

Comment: Hi pgl, My data format is in string or character format : 2010-01 though , so I can't use this function.

Comment: @JPC Sure you can - just manually add "-01" to the end beforehand. Either interpolate it in your query ("SELECT '$date-01'...") or in the query itself: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT('$d', '-01'), '%b')

Comment: oh hey, this one work like a charm !! thank you ! thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this page: [SQL FORMAT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_format.asp), or any of the two above answers.

If you needed more than what the inbouild SQl functions would do, you could do this using whatever language you are using alongside SQL (ie. PHP ect.)

Comment: I did try both , but it gave me "null"

Comment: Have you tried doing it through PHP, or anything similar? (That's what I would do, if I were you)